# What is the delay incurred by ternary content-addressable memory (TCAM)?

Tags: memory, asic

What is the cost (in terms of delay) of using TCAM? How do they compare with SRAM and DRAM?

I understand their use cases are different. But assume, for an application, I can do an operation using TCAM and can also do the operation using RAM. Now in RAM I can access data with memory index. But in TCAM I can do 3 wat matching. But if that specific operation is not so much frequent I can use the RAM. But for that I need to understand the performance difference (in terms of time) between SRAM, DRAM and TCAM. Any reference is most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the cost (in terms of delay) of using TCAM? How do they compare with SRAM and DRAM?

You can't make a general statement on that at all. Ideal TCAM will let all memory cells do their mask/tag comparison in parallel. The addressing then won't actually take longer than the underlying storage cell – it just takes way more logic, and power.

Whether or not it's implemented as a fully parallel comparison, or whether there are a couple layers of indirect addressing above to keep the complexity at bay is up to your actual TCAM implementation.

Comment: Assuming direct addressing, what is the cost in terms of accessing time.?

Comment: I answered that. First sentence.